# No agent could be found with the following capabilities: grunt

Tags: node.js, tfs, gruntjs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

When I try to queue a build on my on-premises TFS 2015 Update 1 I get the following error message:

> No agent could be found with the following capabilities: grunt

I've already installed *NodeJS* and `grunt-cli` and they're in the *path* (i.e. they can be executed in cmd from any location).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your pool settings page: http://SERV_NAME:8080/tfs/_admin/_AgentPool and select your agent, verify that grunt is added as a system capability with the correct path set. If it's not there, you can manually add it as a user capability

[image]

Something recalculates the system capabilities but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer. I'll try it tomorrow. I temporarily solved it running a command-line executable using a build step... but I prefer to go this way, at least to see the big pig head in the build setup lol

Comment: :) Let me know if you figure out how to force a system capability refresh!

Comment: Do you mean how to avoid a full system reboot or Windows service restart?

Comment: Oh ok, if it's as simple as that then fine. I didn't think that a reboot or service restart does it, I've never looked into it to be honest. If you were to force that capability refresh then grunt should automatically appear as a capability and thus problem solved.

Comment: Hey, I've tried this. Now the build says: *Cannot link the argument to `Path` parameter* (I'm not sure if this is the exact message in English because I had to translate it from Spanish)

Comment: Sorry, it's: *Cannot link the argument to Path parameter because it's null*

Comment: I got the message in English: *Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null*

Comment: Hmm that might be something more to do with grunt, which I'm not familiar with. It looks like a PowerShell error, any idea which script it's running. It will usually tell you in the logs

Comment: BTW, I don't see what's the advantage of using this custom task or just starting Grunt using a Powershell step :\

Comment: Probably just to get the pig head lol. In truth some custom steps are pointless imo

Comment: Yeah. I guess the Grunt task should be there for better console output or who knows what. Well, I'll mark your answer as the right one since it solved the capabality thing...

Comment: Cool cheers, I'm just looking into what the grunt step does, will let you know if I have any ideas

Comment: Ok, I'll look forward for your comments if you find something about the topic. For now, my build works the other way but it would look cooler if I could see the pig head :D

Comment: For me a system reboot helped refresh the system capabilities.