# First build of Node.JS application in TFS 2015 Update2

Tags: javascript, node.js, tfs, continuous-integration, tfs-2015

I'm trying to build my first (Hello world) app in Node.js.
I was reading following tutorial:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/node/nodejs-to-azure

My problem is that after clicking Queue Build I have following alert:
"No agent could be found with the following capabilities: **npm, node.js**".

And actually... this is true. 
Where I can found a specific version to be installed on my TFS server?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This could help => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742138/no-agent-could-be-found-with-the-following-capabilities-grunt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was so easy :-).
I installed Node.Js from official site, and then I restarted VSO Agent in services.msc